# How to validate a textbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Following code creates a table & a textbox in jQuery.

```
 var table = $("#dynamic-table").children();
 var row = $('<tr class="data"></tr>');
 row.append($('<td ><input type="text" value=' + item.Marks1 + '
               size="10px" class="marks" id="txtmarks1"  ></td>'));
```

I'm trying to validate the textbox using following code which is not working.

```
$(".data").delegate(".marks","keyup",function () {        
    if ($('#txtmarks1').val().length > 2) {          
        if ($('#txtmarks1').val() > 100) {
            alert("does not exceed 100");
        }
    }
});
```

If it is not the correct way to validate then please suggest a solution.

Comment: you can try jquery validationEngine plugin.
http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

Comment: which version of jquery do you have??

Comment: I just used this jquery-1.8.0.min.js and jquery.ui.core.js

Comment: so try:
$('#dynamic-table').on("keyup",".marks",function () {        
    if ($('#txtmarks1').val().length > 2) {          
        if ($('#txtmarks1').val() > 100) {
            alert("does not exceed 100");
        }
    }
})  ;

Comment: @jain its not working

Comment: try my answer once !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event target section `$(".data")` and target selector `".marks"` both added after page load

so you `delegate()` method won't target section `.data` selector class
you should use parent selector that is load on page load or `document` for delegate selector section

```
$(document).delegate(".marks","keyup",function () {        
    if ($('#txtmarks1').val().length > 2) {          
        if ($('#txtmarks1').val() > 100) {
            alert("does not exceed 100");
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I used this fine working but second time validation is not working

Comment: probably there js syntax error after event fired so second time stop working, if you can create js fiddle that would be useful to trace exact issue

Comment: My textbox values coming from database so i cant prepare the js fiddle

Comment: If i give  more than 3 numbers automatically that number should removed and give alert how can do this

Comment: assign empty string value in `element` if condition true  `if ($('#txtmarks1').val() > 100) { alert("does not exceed 100"); $('#txtmarks1').val(""); }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69784/discussion-between-meena-and-girish).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".marks").keyup(function () {    
    if ($(this).val().length > 2) {          
        if ($(this).val() > 100) {
            alert("does not exceed 100");
        }
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cn0yscnh/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("body").delegate(".data .marks","keyup",function () {        
    if ($('#txtmarks1').val().length > 2) {          
        if ($('#txtmarks1').val() > 100) {
        alert("does not exceed 100");
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
$(".data").change(".marks","keyup",function () {        
    if ($('#txtmarks1').val().length > 2) {          
        if ($('#txtmarks1').val() > 100) {
            alert("does not exceed 100");
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cn0yscnh/1/)**

```
   $(document).on('keyup', ".marks", function () {  
     if ($(this).val().length > 2) {          
         if ($(this).val() > 100) {
           alert("does not exceed 100");
         }
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#dynamic-table').off('keyup').on("keyup",".marks",function () { 
      if ($('#txtmarks1').val().length > 2) { 
        if ($('#txtmarks1').val() > 100) { 
             alert("does not exceed 100"); 
        } 
     } 
}) ;
```